# transfer file at iperf bandwidth/throughput

Tags: file-transfer, netcat, iperf

I need to transfer a file between 2 servers, the output of `iperf` is:

```
TCP window size: 85.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local X.X.X.X port 58986 connected with Y.Y.Y.Y port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  4.00 MBytes  3.35 Mbits/sec
```

I am using `netcat` with something like this from the origin:

```
pv 100GB.file | lz4c | nc Y.Y.Y.Y 9999
```

And in the target `Y.Y.Y.Y` host:

```
nc -l 9999 | lz4c -d -| pv > 100GB.file
```

With this method, the max speed I can get is:`390KiB/s`

Any idea of what protocol or method could I use to get speed like when using `iperf` ~ `3MiB/s`

Comment: have you tried to uncompressed transfer? reync and scp can do the same

Comment: using `rsync -aHAXxv --numeric-ids --delete --progress -e "ssh -o Compression=no -x" user@host:/100GB.file .` I am getting ~ `382.29kB/s`

Comment: rsync does not use Compression by default, and please read my first sentence from my first post

Comment: hi yes, the same thing compressing or not compressing

Comment: use screen and let it run ;) it looks to me for a limitation of bandwidth